# How do I get BASH to understand that that a two digit decimal is greater than one?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get BASH to return a result where if a particular software version contains two decimals values, that it's greater than one?

Example, I would like the result to confirm that 1.12 is greater than 1.8:

```
1.12 > 1.8
```

Since .8 > .1#, I'm not getting the results I want. I've tried various ways such as:

```
version='1.11'
if [[ $version} > 1.8 ]]'; then
...
```

I've also tried to see if I could get 'bc' calculator to return a different result, but unfortunately it also does not provide the result that I'm after:

```
echo 1.11'>'1.8 |bc
0
echo 1.9'>'1.8 |bc
1
```

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved?

Comment: I should mention that this *is* for version control comparisons. So the whole integer value also needs to be accounted for.

Answer (score 2):

suggestion:

```
version1='1.11'
version2='2.8'

maxWidth=3

while [[ ${#version1} -le $maxWidth ]]; do
    version1="${version1}0"
done
while [[ ${#version2} -le $maxWidth ]]; do
    version2="${version2}0"
done

[[ ${version2/\.} -gt ${version1/\.} ]] && echo "v2>v1" || echo "v2<=v1"
```

fix for antak's remark

Comment: Umm.. `version=2.8 version2=1.11` becomes `111 -gt 28` and this logic breaks.